# How to use the method of DataInputStream to read data writed by DataOutputStream.writeBytes(String)?

Tags: java, io

How to use the method of DataInputStream to read data writed by DataOutputStream.writeBytes(String)?

I really have no idea of this problem!

Comment: Are you only using the `writeBytes(String)`? Or other `DataOutputStream` methods as well?

Answer (score 2):

`writeBytes(String)` does not include any indication of the length written so unless you have output the length earlier there is no way to know how much to read.

Also note that `writeBytes(String)` only writes the bottom eight bits of each character in the string discarding the high bits - this may not be what you want.

If you want to write out a `String` look at `writeUTF` which does include the string length and can be read with `DataInputStream.readUTF`.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your `DataOutputStream` with an `ByteArrayOutputStream` and your `DataInputStream` with an `ByteArrayInputStream` using as buffer the byte array from  `ByteArrayOutputStream`, for instance:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream inMemory = new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream (inMemory);

DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream (new ByteArrayInputStream  (inMemory.toByteArray()));
```